# Changes in the fxml file are not visible

Tags: javafx

Basically when i update my .fxml file, i can't see the new stuff...it's like showing the old version of the .fxml...with the old stuff... and yes i save the file...
This is my `Main.java`

```
package Library.Assistant.Ui.Main;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class MainLoader extends Application {

    public static void main(String arg[]) {
        launch(arg);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("Main.fxml"));
        
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }
}
```

This is my `Main.fxml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import com.jfoenix.controls.JFXButton?>
<?import com.jfoenix.controls.JFXTextField?>
<?import javafx.geometry.Insets?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.ListView?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Menu?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.MenuBar?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.MenuItem?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Tab?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TabPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TextField?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.Image?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.ImageView?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.ColumnConstraints?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.HBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.RowConstraints?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox?>

<VBox maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="548.0" prefWidth="617.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/11.0.1" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="Library.Assistant.Ui.Main.MainController">
   <children>
      <MenuBar maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308">
        <menus>
          <Menu mnemonicParsing="false" text="File">
            <items>
              <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Close" />
            </items>
          </Menu>
          <Menu mnemonicParsing="false" text="Edit">
            <items>
              <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Delete" />
            </items>
          </Menu>
          <Menu mnemonicParsing="false" text="Help">
            <items>
              <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="About" />
            </items>
          </Menu>
        </menus>
      </MenuBar>
      <GridPane fx:id="grid" maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" VBox.vgrow="ALWAYS">
        <columnConstraints>
          <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
          <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
        </columnConstraints>
        <rowConstraints>
          <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
          <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
            <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
            <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
            <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
        </rowConstraints>
         <children>
            <TabPane maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" tabClosingPolicy="UNAVAILABLE" GridPane.rowSpan="2147483647">
              <tabs>
                <Tab text="Book Issue">
                     <content>
                        <VBox alignment="CENTER" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="100.0">
                           <children>
                              <HBox alignment="CENTER" maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" VBox.vgrow="ALWAYS">
                                 <children>
                                    <TextField fx:id="enterBookID" promptText="Enter Book ID" />
                                    <VBox alignment="CENTER" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="100.0" HBox.hgrow="ALWAYS">
                                       <children>
                                          <Label text="Book Name" />
                                          <Label text="Author" />
                                       </children>
                                    </VBox>
                                 </children>
                              </HBox>
                              <HBox alignment="CENTER" layoutX="10.0" layoutY="10.0" maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" VBox.vgrow="ALWAYS">
                                 <children>
                                    <TextField promptText="Enter Member ID" />
                                    <VBox alignment="CENTER" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="100.0" HBox.hgrow="ALWAYS">
                                       <children>
                                          <Label text="Member Name" />
                                          <Label text="Contact" />
                                       </children>
                                    </VBox>
                                 </children>
                              </HBox>
                              <HBox alignment="CENTER" layoutX="10.0" layoutY="404.0" maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" VBox.vgrow="ALWAYS">
                                 <children>
                                    <JFXButton maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" text="Issue" HBox.hgrow="ALWAYS" />
                                 </children>
                              </HBox>
                           </children>
                        </VBox>
                     </content>
                </Tab>
                <Tab text="Renew / Submission">
                     <content>
                        <VBox maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308">
                           <children>
                              <BorderPane maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" VBox.vgrow="ALWAYS">
                                 <top>
                                    <JFXTextField alignment="CENTER" promptText="Enter Book ID" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
                                       <BorderPane.margin>
                                          <Insets bottom="20.0" left="10.0" right="10.0" top="10.0" />
                                       </BorderPane.margin>
                                    </JFXTextField>
                                 </top>
                                 <center>
                                    <ListView maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER" />
                                 </center>
                                 <bottom>
                                    <HBox maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
                                       <children>
                                          <JFXButton maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" text="Renew" HBox.hgrow="ALWAYS" />
                                          <JFXButton maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" text="Submission" HBox.hgrow="ALWAYS" />
                                       </children>
                                       <BorderPane.margin>
                                          <Insets />
                                       </BorderPane.margin>
                                    </HBox>
                                 </bottom>
                              </BorderPane>
                           </children>
                        </VBox>
                     </content>
                </Tab>
              </tabs>
            </TabPane>
            <Button contentDisplay="TOP" maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Add Member" GridPane.columnIndex="1">
               <graphic>
                  <ImageView fitHeight="50.0" fitWidth="50.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true">
                     <image>
                        <Image url="@add_mem.png" />
                     </image>
                  </ImageView>
               </graphic>
            </Button>
            <Button contentDisplay="TOP" maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Add Book" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="1">
               <graphic>
                  <ImageView fitHeight="50.0" fitWidth="50.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true">
                     <image>
                        <Image url="@add_book.png" />
                     </image>
                  </ImageView>
               </graphic>
            </Button>
            <Button contentDisplay="TOP" maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" mnemonicParsing="false" text="View Members" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="2">
               <graphic>
                  <ImageView fitHeight="50.0" fitWidth="50.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true">
                     <image>
                        <Image url="@list_mem.png" />
                     </image>
                  </ImageView>
               </graphic>
            </Button>
            <Button contentDisplay="TOP" maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" mnemonicParsing="false" text="View Books" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="3">
               <graphic>
                  <ImageView fitHeight="50.0" fitWidth="50.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true">
                     <image>
                        <Image url="@list_book.png" />
                     </image>
                  </ImageView>
               </graphic>
            </Button>
            <Button contentDisplay="TOP" maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Settings" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="4">
               <graphic>
                  <ImageView fitHeight="50.0" fitWidth="50.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true">
                     <image>
                        <Image url="@settings.png" />
                     </image>
                  </ImageView>
               </graphic>
            </Button>
         </children>
      </GridPane>
   </children>
</VBox>
```

I just can't understand why it's showing the old version of the file...yesterday everything was working fine.I was adding new stuff and it was showing them properly, but today it keeps showing the version from yesterday...no matter how many stuff i change..

Comment: [mcve] please ...

Comment: Clean and rebuild the project.